# checking if variable is NULL

Tags: vb.net, variables, null, pdfsharp

I am working on a project with PDFSharp. Sadly as a VB.Net developer, the examples they provided were written in C#. I'm having a problem of checking if a variable is `null`.

On C#, the code is declared like this

```
PdfDictionary resources = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources");
  if (resources != null) 
  'do stuff here
```

Im having a problem with the second line,

> if (resources !=null)

So far, this is what I've done on VB, and I have also read [this Blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/nothing-vs-null.html) from sLaks.

> Dim resources As New PdfDictionary?()

But it is giving me some errors.

Simply setting resources to `nothing` would yield its default value, could be an int, or whatsoever. I wanted it to be compared to a NULL. 
This is the full [code](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7):

If you've done:

`Dim resources As New PdfDictionary?()`

Then resources will not be nothing as you've just instantiated it to something.

What you're likely after is

```
Dim resources As PdfDictionary = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources")
  IF resources IsNot Nothing THEN
  'do stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim resources As PdfDictionary = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources")
  IF Not resources Is Nothing THEN
  'do stuff
```

Works as well. It's builder's choice on this one.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid many nested ifs and foreach i would success to do somekind of returning if resources is null.
Like this:

```
If resources Is Nothing Then
 Exit Sub / Return / Throw New Exception("Resources cannot be loaded")...
End If
```

... rest of code ..